# Transaction for ASP .net Membership

Tags: asp.net, transactions

I would like to make two database operation in one transaction. Those two operations are

1. Do one insert operation.
2. Create one user (using membership - sql membership provider)

I tried **TransactionScope** but it went to distributed transaction at that line:
          -- Membership.CreateUser("test", "password", "test@test.com");

How can I do this with lightweight transaction since I have only DB?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

The current implementation of TransactionScope will only use a lightweight transaction if you use a single database connection.  So it is not possible to achieve this in your scenario.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar problem. My resolution is (I'm still not sure its going to work) to download the ASP.Net Membership Provider code and rebuild it, hijacking the SqlConnectionHolder class.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this topic and I think I have found an answer. It only applies to SQLServer 2008. It does not require changes to System.Transactions namespace or our Application code. It's interesting. ;)

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/03/26/extending-lightweight-transactions-in-sqlclient.aspx

Hope this helps!

Comment: Providing more information about the solution then just a link will make your answer more helpful.