# How to use SQL membership with transaction scope (without DTC)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-membership, sql-server-express, transactionscope

I'm trying to create a user using the SQL membership provider on **SQL Express**. When I use the `TransactionScope` it prompts to DTC with no apparent reason, how can I avoid it?

Here is my example code:

```
using (var ts = new TransactionScope())
{
    MembershipCreateStatus status;
    Membership.CreateUser(username, password, null, null, null, true, out status);

    var userProfile = ProfileBase.Create(username);

    userProfile.SetPropertyValue("Fullname", fullname);
    userProfile.Save();

    ts.Complete();
}
```

BTW, I checked in reflector and every membership SQL function always closes its connection.

Comment: See also [Transaction for ASP .net Membership](http://stackoverflow.com/q/304692/49942)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement this function without a transaction as suggested [here](http://forums.asp.net/p/1475217/3427486.aspx).

Comment: The answer in your link (which appears to be 'Or Betzalel' on forums.asp.net,) doesn't answer the question...

Comment: It's not him, I posted this question from SO, I'm SharpOne.

Comment: IMO that doesn't really provide a quality solution. What happens if your profile save fails?  Now you have a membership record with no profile record. There has to be a better way...

Comment: This really doesn't answer the question